# Printing char type yields nothing

Tags: java

I am studying for the Java Certification. In the book that I'm reading it has a line that's written:

```
char c = 65;
System.out.println(c); //Prints "A"
```

And in the next example this line:

```
char seven = 7; //number, cause it's not in single quotes
System.out.println(seven); // doesn't print anything
```

I didn't understand why. Can someone explain, please?

Comment: Java `char`(s) are integral types. See also the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: You should consider that suggestions that you look at ASCII might be misleading and not match the way you learn. People are giving you a simple character set with one encoding. Like many modern languages, Java uses Unicode and its UTF-16 encoding for String and char. Files and streams often use Unicode's UTF-8 encoding. A `char` stores one UTF-16 code unit. (That's all over the Java documentation.) Some people, for whatever reason, call that an "ASCII value," which is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char` type is a UTF-16 character code unit, and the integer is a character code. For ASCII, 65 is A, and 7 is BEL (or BELL) where nothing is printed, but an audible sound is emitted. From [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/2299-how-to-emit-a-beep-by-printing-the-ascii-bell-character-to-the-console.html):

> Bell character is the control code used to sound an audible bell or tone in order to alert the user (ASCII 7, EBCDIC 2F). Bell character is an ASCII control character, code 7 (^G). When it is sent to a printer or a terminal, nothing is printed, but an audible signal is emitted instead.

You can also view an ASCII table [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Comment: "`char` type, the integer is treated as a character code, based on the system": This is false. A Java `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. Conversion from `int` to `char` preserves the value.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign an integer to `char`, it sets the `ASCII` value to the character. ASCII char of value 7 is not printable anything (BEL). That's why it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses unicode to represent characters. The standard set of characters known as ASCII still ranges from 0 to 127 as always and unicode added support for extra characters required to support other international languages.

As given in [link](http://www.ascii-code.com/) 65-90 are codes for A-Z, 97-122 are codes for a-z and there are codes for other characters too. Play around these numbers and your program prints all printable characters. Your program is not printing anything for second print statement because ASCII 7 is not printable.

Comment: Nit picking on the term "international": Unicode supports writing systems for languages that are used by only one country, too (for example, Tagalog); and, no current country, too (for example, Sumerian).

Answer (score 0):

The numbers of your chars are in hexadecimal and come from the ASCII Table.
Your "7" is a "control symbol".
They have no symbol.

Take a look at the table.
http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm

The "65" is your A which was printed.